# How can I extract a pattern from a text when it involves a new line?

Tags: python, pandas, text, pattern-matching, text-processing

Say I have following text in a cell of a dataset (csv file):

[image]

I want to extract the words/phrase that appears after the keywords `Decision` and `reason`. I can do it like so:

```
import pandas as pd

text = '''Decision: Postpone\n\nreason:- medical history -  information obtained from attending physician\n\nto review with current assessment from Dr Cynthia Dominguez regarding medical history, and current CBC showing actual number of platelet count\n\nmib: F\n'''

keywords = ['decision', 'reason']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=[0], columns=keywords)

a = text.split('\n')
for cell in a:
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in cell.lower():
            if len(cell.split(':'))>1:
                new_df[keyword][0]=cell.split(':')[1]

new_df
```

[image]

***However, in some of the cells, the words/phrases appear in a new line after the keyword, in which case this program is unable to extract it:***

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

text = '''Decision: Postpone\n\nreason: \n- medical history \n-  information obtained from attending physician\n\nto review with current assessment from Dr Cynthia Dominguez regarding medical history, and current CBC showing actual number of platelet count\n\nmib: F\n'''

keywords = ['decision', 'reason']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=[0], columns=keywords)

a = text.split('\n')
for cell in a:
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in cell.lower():
            if len(cell.split(':'))>1:
                new_df[keyword][0]=cell.split(':')[1]
new_df
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular expression to split data this would reduced number of loops

```
import re
import pandas as pd

text = '''Decision: Postpone\n\nreason: \n- medical history \n-  information obtained from attending physician\n\nto review with current assessment from Dr Cynthia Dominguez regarding medical history, and current CBC showing actual number of platelet count\n\nmib: F\n'''

keywords = ['decision', 'reason']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=[0], columns=keywords)
text =text.lower()
tokens = re.findall(r"[\w']+", text)
for key in keywords:
   if key =='decision':
     index = tokens.index(key)
     new_df[key][0] = ''.join(tokens[index+1:index+2])
   if key =='reason':
     index = tokens.index(key)
     meta = tokens.index('review')
     new_df[key][0] = " ".join(tokens[index + 1:meta -1])

print(new_df)
```

Comment: This also extracts the text below reasons ("`to review with current assessment from...`") which should not be extracted under `reason`.

Comment: text you provided contains text = '''Decision: Postpone\n\nreason: \nmedical history \n\nto review with current assessment from Dr Cynthia Dominguez regarding medical history, and current CBC showing actual number of platelet count\n\nmib: F\n''' after reason it is not in the end

Comment: Yes, but that part "to review with..." should not be extracted in the `reason` column, as it is some meta information.

Comment: @Kristada673 thanks for the feedback I have updated the code

Comment: Thanks. The problem with your code is that it would work for this very specific input text. But the dataset I have contains several kinds of text - the meta information is not always present; if its present, the word "review" is not necessarily in all of them; sometimes the word "reason" is missing but you can see the phrase "due to medical reasons", etc.

Comment: @Kristada673 you are right.According to my Knowledge you cant write generic code for all kind of examples but what you can do is take apply try catch and try to figure out those words which could be used as a meta and check those in multiple if else cases

Answer (score 0):

If the content is in another row, you definitely may not split the
source string into rows and then look for all "tokens" in thee
current row.

Instead you should:

- prepare a *regex* with 2 capturing groups (keyword and content),
- look for matches, e.g. using *finditer*.

Example code can be as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=keywords)
keywords = ['decision', 'reason']
it = re.finditer(r'(?P<kwd>\w+):\n?(?P<cont>.+?(?=\n\w+:|$))',
    text, flags=re.DOTALL)
row = dict.fromkeys(keywords, '')
for m in it:
    kwd = m.group('kwd').lower()
    cont = m.group('cont').strip()
    if kwd in keywords:
        row[kwd] = cont
df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

Of course, you should start from *import re*.

And maybe you should also read a little about regular expressions.